# Numerate versus Enumerate

Tags: meaning, punctuation

I am not a native speaker.

I am writing a technical report and I should numerate/enumerate several equations in the entire document. Thus, is there any difference in using **Numerate** or **Enumerate** as verb?

Example: We enumerated (or numerated) several equations in the manuscript.

Comment: Use *enumerate*. End of story.

Comment: Robusto's advice is sound—but I can see why a nonnative speaker might be perplexed by the entry for _numerate_ in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_: "**numerate** _vt_ (1657) : ENUMERATE." It would be easy to infer that MW considers the two words to be equivalent (and even, perhaps, interchangeable), especially since there is no hint that _numerate_ is rare or a variant form.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to identify each equation with a number, then neither word is right. You should just "number" the equations.

[Number](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/number?s=t):

> to mark with or distinguish by numbers:

[Enumerate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enumerate) does not specifically mean to actually include numbers:

> 1. to mention separately as if in counting; name one by one; specify, as in a list: *Let me enumerate the many flaws in your hypothesis.*
> 2. to ascertain the number of; count.

[Numerate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/numerate?s=t:) as a verb means to use something other than actual numbers:

> to represent numbers by symbols.

Answer (score 0):

**Numerate**

[Random House's English Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/numerate?s=t) defines *numerate* as

> To represent numbers by symbols.

[Collin's English Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/numerate?s=t) defines *numerate* as

> To read a numerical expression"

Considering the definitions from the dictionaries that distinguish between the two, it seems that we might regard the word as roughly meaning.

> To use numbers or numerals in order to express meaning.

When one reads a numerical expression, one uses numbers to express meaning. When one uses a numeral to express a numeric concept (e.g. *5* for the concept of five of something), one uses a numeral in order to express meaning.

---

**Enumerate**

According to [Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/enumerate) *enumerate* relates to totals.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=enumerate&submit.x=52&submit.y=23), a prescriptive dictionary (i.e. a dictionary that defines words by their best use, as opposed to their most common use), *enumerate* means

> To determine the number of.

Accordingly, one might correctly write "The teacher enumerated thirty children in the class room".

---

**Number**

The verb *number* is appropriate if you want to express the assignment of numbers to things, such as items on a list.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=number&submit.x=50&submit.y=38) defines the verb *number* thus:

> To assign a number to something.

Comment: Is that (use of "numerate" as a verb) American? Would you add the relevant hyperlink to "word-net"?

Comment: @ChrisW I've removed that definition. I didn't find anything equivalent in any other dictionary. The authors of Word-Net often seem to sacrifice precision in order to group words more easily. I suspect that its definition of *numerate* is evidence of one instance of that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never (in Canadian and British English) heard "numerate" used as a verb.

This [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/numerate) defines "numerate" only as an adjective (like "literate"): not as a verb.

> Definition of numerate in English:
>   adjective
>
> Having a good basic knowledge of arithmetic; able to understand and work with numbers:
>   teachers should ensure that their pupils are literate and numerate

The *verb* is "to enumerate", or "to number" or "to count".

Answer (score 0):

To 'numerate' and to 'enumerate' mean to *list in sequence*.

If your report does not list the equations one after the other, but considers them individually, each in its separate context,  you could say instead "we addressed (or considered or discussed) several equations in the manuscript".